# Error whle trying to extract city names from a text using geograpy library in python

Tags: python, geography

This is the code i tried

```
from geograpy.extraction import Extractor
    import geograpy

text = """Kadawatha Opposition Leader Mahinda Rajapaksa says that the whole  public administration has collapsed due to the constitution council’s arbitrary actions.
    The Opposition Leader said so in response to a query a journalised raised  after a meeting held in Malabe and Meegamuwa"""
    places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)
    print(places.places)
```

Then it give an error

[image]

[image]

Thanks, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [this](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy) is the `geography` package you are using, `Install & Setup` section says you also need to download the models they are using:

> Geograpy uses NLTK for entity recognition, so you'll also need to download the models we're using. Fortunately there's a command that'll take care of this for you:
>
> geograpy-nltk

Did you download the models?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it and install with below command:

```
pip install geograpy3
```